# Create React App modifies font size in Safari

Tags: css, safari, create-react-app

I ran into a really strange issue and I can't really get my head around what is happening here. I was working on the theming of my recent **React App** when I realised that the default font size is different in Safari than in Chrome or Firefox. At first I thought this has to do with responsive font sizing since I know that Safari treats the `rem` values differently. Thus, for testing purposes, I have created a fresh install of **CRA** and tested a header and a paragraph with fixed font sizes:

```css
h1 { font-size: 32px; }
p { font-size: 16px; }
```

Unfortunately it happened again and the result can be seen here:

[image: Font size comparison Create React App. From left to right: Chrome, FF, Safari]

There is about a 4px difference between Chrome / FF and Safari. When checking the developer tools of the individual browsers, all of them show the right font size (and line height).

I thought this might have something to do with Safari (since it seems that this browser is on the path of being the new Internet Explorer), so I have created a simple HTML 5 page to test the behaviour again. This is the result:

[image: Font size comparison HTML 5 page. From left to right: Chrome, FF, Safari]

As you can see, everything appears as expected which indicates it has nothing to do with Safari.

I have also tried to reset the CSS with `normalize.css` but no success either. Did anyone else experience this problem?

My setup:

```
SYSTEM --
Mac OS 11.0.1
Safari 14.0.1
Chrome for Mac 86.0.4240.198
Firefox for Mac 82.0.3

CRA -- 4.0.1
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-scripts": "4.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^0.2.4"

"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around for hours, setting up test projects and trying to verify the results on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io), I found out that (occasionally) Safari is setting the **initial zoom level to `125%`.** Since this is not always the case I am not sure if it has something to do with my system or it is really something with CRA and Safari...

I would be great to hear if anyone has been experiencing the same issue.

Sorry if I have been wasting anybody's time here!

Answer (score 0):

Updating the public/index.html meta tag for the viewport in my React app from:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

seems to have worked for me on Safari.